Expect the size of a filtered `ChainablePromiseArray` in WebdriverIO v9
I am quite new to WebdriverIO.
I have some experience with TestCafe, but the way expectations work is fundamentally different.
I want to add the "Missing support for attributes, properties and visible in waitForElement" in @wdio/chrome-recorder
Given a step (from Chrome Recorder) like this:
{
    "type": "waitForElement",
    "target": "main",
    "selectors": [
        ".becomesVisible"
    ],
    "operator": "==",
    "count": 1,
    "visible": true
}

The current result from @webdriverio/chrome-recorder looks like this
await expect(browser.$$(".becomesVisible")).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(1)

The approach is straight forward: $$ returns something resembling an Array (ChainablePromiseArray). Depending on the operator, the size of this "array" is expected.
But whats missing here is the check, if the selected elements are actually visible.
(Its also possible, to define properties and attributes, that must match, but that's not in the scope of this question.)
ChainablePromiseArray even has a filter which plays nicely with Promises.
The most straight forward approach I came up with was:
await expect($$(`.becomesVisible`).filter(el => el.isDisplayed())).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(1);

But this fails, because toBeElementsArrayOfSize seems to only work on ChainablePromiseArrays
The next logical step was to wrap the result in $$ because is supposed to work with arrays for initialization.
await expect($$($$(`.becomesVisible`).filter(el => el.isDisplayed()))).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(1);

But this did not work either. I assume, because filter returns a Promise.
So I tried to await the filter.
await expect($$(await $$(`.becomesVisible`).filter(el => el.isDisplayed()))).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(1);

This works as long as there are matching elements in the DOM, when the filter is executed.
But this kills all this automatic waiting.
At this point I am lost.
The only "solution" I came up with, was this:
await expect($$(function(this: Window) {
    return Array.from((this as Window).document.querySelectorAll(`.becomesVisible`))
        .filter(el => 
            el.computedStyleMap().get("display")?.toString() !== "none" &&
            el.computedStyleMap().get("visibility")?.toString() !== "hidden"
        )
})).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(1);

But I am not really happy with recreating all the logic that is already there.
Is there a solution that uses existing logic?
